# $\ell_{3}$ projection on the cone of positive semi-definite matrices.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $A=[a_{ij}]_{n \times n}$ be a symmetric matrix. Define $\|A\|_{3} := \big( \sum_{ij} |a_{ij}|^3 \big)^{\frac{1}{3}}$, the usual $\ell_{3}$ norm on the space of matrices.

My question is whether the projection on $S^n_+$, the cone of positive semidefinite matrices, has a closed form with respect to the above norm? In other words, if the following convex optimization problem has a closed solution, or at least has a close formula for its optimal value.

$$\begin{equation}\label{conso}
\mbox{minimize} \;\;  \|X-A\|_{3}^{3}   \quad \mbox{subject to}\;\;   X \in S^n_{+}
\end{equation}$$

I know when the norm is $\ell_{2}$, the answer is yes because we can write the $\ell_{2}$ based on the trace.